# How to check if the first coordinate of each tuple in lst is a data type

Tags: haskell

Assuming we have a data type

```
type PName = String

data Prin = Name PName | Together Prin Prin | Quote Prin Prin 
             deriving (Eq, Show)
```

in Haskell, it will take a list `lst` (of type `[(Prin,a)]`) as input, return true if the first coordinate of each tuple in `lst` is a simple principal. Otherwise it will return False.

Example:

```
check :: [(Prin,a)] -> Bool
```

```
output::Bool
output = check[(a,1),(b,2),(Name "a" , 3)]
```

which is return true because there is not data type in input but if

```
output = check [(Quot x y,1),(Together x y, 2)]
```

which will return false because it have data type in input.

Can someone explain it how this is happen?

```
isSimple :: [(Prin,Int)] -> Bool
isSimple (x:xs,y:ys) 
    | (x,y) ==(Quote x x ,y) = isSimple (xs,ys)
    | otherwise = False
```

Not sure am I on the right track or not.

Comment: What's a simple principal? You probably want to use `all :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> Bool`.

Comment: Data prin is simple princple

Comment: Do you mean `Name`? You need to explain what your code is actually doing. "Principal" doesn't mean anything to anyone who isn't familiar with the problem you are trying to solve or the data you are trying to model.

Answer (score 0):

I'm kinda filling in some gaps in your explanation of what you want to do, but it sounds like you're asking something like

```hs
isSimple (Name _) : xs = isSimple ...
isSimple _ : _ = False
isSimple [] = ...
```

I've left some tiny ellipses for you to figure out.
The techniques used here are pattern matching and recursion.
Chepner is correct that you can leave the recursion implicit by using the `all` function instead.